# Kinetics of the conversion from metal oxide to metal hydroxide in water

Tags: ions, solutions, metal

How long can a metal oxide such as magnesium oxide remain in solution before being converted to the metal hydroxide?

Comment: Rate is dependent on many factors such as temperature and concentration.

Comment: This will happen very fast. What do you need this info for?

Comment: Satisfaction of curiosity.